# Как собрать все теги на странице?

Tags: python, html, requests, beautiful-soup

Код:

```
def g():
    r = requests.get()
  

def write_csv(data):
    with open('cmc.csv') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)


def get_page_data():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Как собрать все теги `tr` на странице?
Возвращает только 45.
Конретизировал критерии поиска, возвращет 0 или 45.

Comment: что за .find в конце строки?

Comment: Поправил, это были дополнительные условия поиска тегов. Мои попытки конкретизировать поиск по дереву.

Comment: вы с помощью .find('tbody') получаете только первую таблицу, в ней - около 45 строк...

Comment: Но у меня на странице на много больше записей подходящих под тег(поиска), и всего одна страница на которой находятся все события за определенную дату.

Comment: а trs = soup.find('div', id='center').find_all('tr') (все tr) - не подходит?

Comment: О! вернуло 774. Благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас на странице - несколько таблиц, а код

```
trs = soup.find('div', id='center').find('tbody').find_all('tr')
```

из-за `.find('tbody')` берет только первую из них...

Попробуйте брать просто все-все строки:

```
trs = soup.find('div', id='center').find_all('tr')
```